# Problem in Dead Money DLC ending?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I have just finished the Dead Money DLC for Fallout New Vegas.

When I go to the gate that says "Travel to Mohave Wasteland", it gives the DLC's ending, but after that video ends I'm back in BoS Bunker. I get the full HUD and can move for 1-2 seconds, but after that some poison gas is released in to the room, just like how it starts, I get a black screen and when it goes back I am unable to move and do anything, and have a continuous loop of Christine voice (Vera voice) on the radio.

Is this a bug? I let it play for about 4-5 times and it doesn't stop...

How can I get past this?

Comment: are you playing on PC?

Comment: Yes, playing on PC.

Comment: Please see my answer below, You aren't alone in this bug.

Answer (score 2):

I read in multiple locations that if you save at this point, it is a looped bug as you have experienced.  You aren't alone.  Sadly, you will have to revert to an old save to fix this - at least until a patch is released.

[Here is a list of the known  glitches and patches to fix them (if they exist yet)](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Heist_of_the_Centuries)

Comment: Yes, i saved just at the front of the gate that leads to Mohave. Didn't find any fixes on that page..

Comment: "...at least until a patch is released"

Comment: I really wouldn't expect any more patches for this game at this point

Answer (score 0):

Yeah.. anyway, i started from an earlier save, and didn't saved again at the Mohave Wasteland gate, and then it works fine in BoS Bunker, but if you go back to the radio chamber poison gas is still released and you get stuck again :D. Thanks for answers.